# General formula for integration on $m$-dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($m<n$)?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $S$ be a two-dimensional surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We suppose that $S$ is parameterized as $\vec x (t,s)$, where $t,s$ vary in some region $T$ of the plane. Then the surface integral of a scalar function $f(\vec x)$ over $S$ is given by:

$$\int\int_S f dS = \int\int_T f(\vec x(t,s)) \left| \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial t} \right| dt ds $$

What is the generalization of this formula to hypersurfaces of dimension $m$ embeeded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $m<n$? That is, let $S$ be parameterized as $\vec x(t_1,\dots,t_m)$, where $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t_1,\dots,t_m$ vary over some region of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then how can I express the following hypersurface-integral:

$$\int\dots\int_S f dS$$

as an integration over the variables $t_1,\dots,t_m$? Note that I am assuming the usual Euclidean measures in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1434969/10063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the $n\times m$ Jacobian matrix $J$:

$$
J=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_1} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_m}\\
\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_1} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_m}\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial t_1} & \frac{\partial x_n}{\partial t_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial x_n}{\partial t_m}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then the surface element can be written as:

$$dS = \sqrt{\det (J^{\dagger}J)} dt_1 dt_2\dots dt_m$$

$\det (J^{\dagger}J)$ is just a [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant), giving the $m$-dimensional squared volume of the parallelotope spanned by the $m$ vectors $\partial \vec{x} / \partial t_1$, $\partial \vec{x} / \partial t_2$, $\dots$, $\partial \vec{x} / \partial t_m$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\det(J J^\dagger)$?

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren I had an error in the definition of $J$. Should be fine now.